# Pressure derivative of bulk modulus

Tags: thermodynamics, continuum-mechanics

Hi all what is the definition of pressure derivative of [bulk modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) if it is a pressure derivative of bulk modulus at zero pressure. if the pressure is zero how it is derivative by pressure?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the definition of derivative is still applicable: you take the limit of "modulus at pressure = $\triangle p$ minus modulus at pressure = 0" divided by $\triangle p$ for $\triangle p\rightarrow 0$.